# ReCharts with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I want to create A ReChart component, which has multiple lines.

SO far i have this dummy code.

```js
<LineChart
  data={data}
  margin={{
    top: 16,
    right: 16,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 24
  }}
>
  <XAxis dataKey="time" />
  <YAxis>
    <Label angle={270} position="left" style={{ textAnchor: "middle" }}>
      Cyber assesment
    </Label>
  </YAxis>
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="amount" stroke="#556CD6" dot={false} />
</LineChart>
```

with the data being an array, with a two value object:

```
function createData(time, amount) {
  return { time, amount };
}

const data = [
  createData('00:00', 0),
  createData('03:00', 300),
  createData('06:00', 600),
  createData('09:00', 800),
  createData('12:00', 1500),
  createData('15:00', 2000),
  createData('18:00', 2400),
  createData('21:00', 2400),
  createData('24:00', undefined),
];
```

i want to make it so i can have multiple lines plotted, where i tried creating a different function and adding other data, to the same array, but with no good result.

How can this be achived?

i tried to create a working example, but without any luck

```js
function createData(amountA, amountB) {
  return {a: amountA, b: amountB  };
}

const data = [
  createData(100, 200),
  createData(200, 400),
  createData(400, 500),
  createData(600, 800),
  createData(650, 700),
  createData(900, 800)
];

export default function Chart() {
    console.log(data)
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Title>Performance indication</Title>
      <ResponsiveContainer>
        <LineChart
          data={data}
          margin={{
            top: 16,
            right: 16,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 24,
          }}
        >
          <XAxis dataKey="time" />
          <YAxis>
            <Label angle={270} position="left" style={{ textAnchor: 'middle' }}>
              Cyber assesment
            </Label>
          </YAxis>
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey={data.a} stroke="#556CD6" dot={false} />
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey={data.b} stroke="#556CD6" dot={false} />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your issue is. If you want more than one line plotted, you need to add key in your data object (see https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/xqjtetw0/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just declare two `Line` and two `YAxis` `components` inside your `LineChart` and explicitly declare `yAxisId`. Here is an example of one of ours

```
<LineChart data={data} margin={{ left: -10, right: 10 }}>
    <XAxis height={40} dataKey="part" tick={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
        <Label
            value='Período'
            position='insideBottom'
            fontSize={14}
            fill='#676767'
        />
    </XAxis>
    <YAxis width={80} yAxisId="left" tick={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
        <Label
            value={selected.A}
            angle={-90}
            position='outside'
            fill='#676767'
            fontSize={14}
        />
    </YAxis>
    <YAxis width={80} yAxisId="right" orientation="right" tick={{ fontSize: 10, }}>
        <Label
            value={selected.B}
            angle={-90}
            position='outside'
            fill='#676767'
            fontSize={14}
        />
    </YAxis>
    <Tooltip formatter={(value) => floatParser(value)} />
    <Line yAxisId="left" type="monotone" dataKey={selected.A} stroke={colors[1]} />
    <Line yAxisId="right" type="monotone" dataKey={selected.B} stroke={colors[0]} />
</LineChart>
```

[image]

`data` array:

```
const data = [
    { part: 'foo', axisA: 21211, axisB: 1232 }
]
```

Comment: Could you provide,  your data aswell?

Comment: So the `selected` would just be refered to as `data.axisA` and `data.axisB` in this full example?

Comment: exactly!! Each `Line` refers to a specific data property

Comment: i made an edit, to mimic this behaviour, but i could not get it to work

Comment: I've update the answer. You need two `YAxis` as well

Comment: This should work exactly the same for `Line` and `Area` charts

Comment: where do you specify the names for the y axis?

Comment: `yAxisId` prop. Copy as paste my `Line` and `YAxis` components and give it a try

Comment: For Issue: Multi-line repeats categories on x axis;
set `allowDuplicatedCategory={false}` in `<XAxis>`

Answer (score 6):

With the latest version now you can directly add your data at the component.

like this [Recharts multiple Lines with different datasets](https://jsfiddle.net/465zc9fg/)

```
const data = [
      {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, amt: 2400},
      {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, amt: 2210},
      {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, amt: 2290},
      {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, amt: 2000},
      {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, amt: 2181},
];
const data2 = [
      {name: 'Page A', pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
      {name: 'Page B', pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
      {name: 'Page C', pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
      {name: 'Page D', pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
];

 <Line data={data} type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#8884d8"/>
 <Line data = {data2} type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#82ca9d"/>
```

[Example](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1167#issuecomment-626334437)

Comment: I assume that used to work, but for reference, that fiddle (and my code) has a x-axis twice as long as it should be - i.e. instead of [1, 2, 3] it's [1,2,3,1,2,3]. I haven't found a non-hacky way around it.

Comment: I encounter the same @HammerN'Songs. Which hacks did you apply?

Comment: @flp Sorry, we ended up going with reaviz, which just required the data to be in a specific format, but was eventually doable - though I don't know if it has the ability to smooth lines like how recharts does.

Comment: There is allowDuplicatedCategory={false} settings for XAxis that solves the problem.